# How can i call images from folders and how to draw image with canvas(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I want to draw image file with `canvas` in `javascript` but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Here are my steps to call it.

1. set canvas object

```
        {
        imageSequence: [0, 5],
        imgArray: [],
        canvas: document.querySelector("#imgadd"),
        context: document.querySelector("#imgadd").getContext("2d")     
       
    }
```

2. indexing images and push to `imgArray` and add images automatically with function

```
    //image indexing
    let sequence = Math.round(sceneInfo[0].imageSequence)



    //img add function
    function addImage() {
        let imgadd;

        for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            imgadd = new Image();
            imgadd.src = `./img/${i}.jpg`;
            sceneInfo[0].imgArray.push(imgadd.src);
        }
    }
    addImage()
```

3 add window event to draw image when window loaded

```
    //when window load call function
    window.addEventListener('onload', () => {
        sceneInfo[0].context.drawImage(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[sequence], 0, 0);

    })
```

And here is my whole codes  (set anonymous function)

```js
(() => {
  //canvas setting 
  const sceneInfo = [{
    imageSequence: [0, 5],
    imgArray: [],
    canvas: document.querySelector("#imgadd"),
    context: document.querySelector("#imgadd").getContext("2d")
  }];

  //image indexing
  let sequence = Math.round(sceneInfo[0].imageSequence)

  //img add function
  function addImage() {
    let imgadd;
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
      imgadd = new Image();
      imgadd.src = `./img/${i}.jpg`;
      sceneInfo[0].imgArray.push(imgadd.src);
    }
  }
  addImage();

  //when window load call function
  window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    sceneInfo[0].context.drawImage(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[sequence], 0, 0);
  })

  console.log(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[sequence]);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="imgadd"></anvas>
```

And I would like to know that
when I `console.log(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[sequence]);`
the Array which I push the images, The console window return 'undefined'
I don't know the reason.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imageSequence is an array there is no Math.round to an array, that will give NaN

```js
const sceneInfo = [{
  imageSequence: [0, 5]
}];

let sequence = Math.round(sceneInfo[0].imageSequence)

console.log(sceneInfo[0].imageSequence);
console.log(sequence);
```

---

I have no idea why that complex `sceneInfo` object...
but here is my attempt to fully drawing images and keeping the code as close to your original.

```js
(() => {
  //canvas setting 
  const sceneInfo = [{
    imageSequence: [0, 5],
    imgArray: [],
    canvas: document.querySelector("#imgadd"),
    context: document.querySelector("#imgadd").getContext("2d")
  }];

  //img add function
  function addImage() {
    let imgadd;
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
      let imgadd = new Image();
      sceneInfo[0].imgArray.push(imgadd);
      imgadd.onload = () => {
        sceneInfo[0].context.drawImage(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[i-1], i*40, i*10);
        console.log(sceneInfo[0].imgArray[i-1].src)
      };
      imgadd.src = `http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/Image/?${i}`;
    }
  }
  addImage();
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="imgadd" width=600></canvas>
```

Comment: I try to execute your code but I got an error on chrome development console that "cannot read property 'getContext' of null " Actually it throws same error on my previous code. It happeneds on line that  ```context :document.querySelector("#imgadd").getContext("2d")```

Comment: on chrome development console? why not create a page: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/HTML/canvas_66556422.html

and here is how that looks like: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_66556422.html

Comment: Thank you for your example.
I found out that ```<script>``` location was the problem I have to put it under the ```<body>``` but I didn't.